# Matching TV and Movie File names with Regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I've been working on getting a regular expression to grab the TV Show or Movie name, the year it was aired if it exist, the season #and the episode # from the file name of a video.  I have a regular expression (below) that seems to work well for shows with double year dates (one of the years is in the show/movie name the other is the year it aired) for both movies and TV show.  For TV Show it is able to grab the season and episode numbers if the format is in SXXEXX or XXX.  I've been testing it out in the [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) test engine.  Where I'm struggling is the expression won't return anything if a year does not exist in the filename.  Also if the filename has a 4 digit number that's actually part of the show name it thinks that is the aired year date (i.e. "The 4400").  How can I modify this expression to be able to handle the extra conditions that I described?

The end goal is I want to put this into a python script that queries a site like TheTVDB.com if the file is a movie or TV show so that I can sort my vast video library into TV Show and Movies folders.

```
(?P<ShowName>.*)[ (_.]#Show Name
       (?=19[0-9]\d|20[0-4]\d|2050) #If after the show name is a year
          (?P<ShowYear>\d{4,4}) # Get the show year
          | # Else
          (?=S\d{1,2}E\d{1,2}) 
             S(?P<Season>\d{1,2})E(?P<Episode>\d{1,2}) #Get the season and Episode information
             |
             (\d{1})E(\d{1,2})
```

Here is my test data I'm using

- archer.2009.S04E13
- space 1999 1975
- Space: 1999 (1975)
- Space.1999.1975.S01E01
- space 1999.(1975)
- The.4400.204.mkv
- space 1999 (1975) v.2009.S01E13.the.title.avi
- Teen.wolf.S04E12.HDTV.x264
- Se7en.(1995).avi
- How to train your dragon 2

The regular expression does not work properly with the following test data:

- The.4400.204.mkv
- Teen.wolf.S04E12.HDTV.x264
- How to train your dragon 2

Update: Here is the new expression based on the comments.  It works much better but is struggling with the 3 file names listed below the expressions.

```
(?P<ShowName>.*)#Show Name
(
   [ (_.]
   (
       (?=\d{4,4}) #If after the show name is a year
          (?P<ShowYear>\d{4})  # Get the show year
          | # Else no year in the file name then just grab the name
          (?P<otherShowName>.*) # Grab Show Name
          (?=S\d{1,2}E\d{1,2}) # If the Season Episode patterns matches SX{1,2}EX{1,2}, Then
             S(?P<Season>\d{1,2})E(?P<Episode>\d{1,2}) #Get the season and Episode information
             | # Else
             (?P<Alt_S_E>\d{3,4}) # Get the season and Episode that looks like 211
   )
|$)
```

- Se7en
- 10,000BC (2010)
- v.2009.S01E13.the.title.avi
- archer.2009.S04E13

Comment: It's difficult to tell what all these variations are, especially now with the added examples. What are the show/year/episode parts of `v.2009.S01E13.the.title.avi` and `archer.2009.S04E13`?

Comment: And what's it supposed to do with `space 1999 (1975) v.2009.S01E13.the.title.avi`? What's the show name? Is 2009 the year?

Comment: If the file name input is v.2009.S01E13.the.title.avi.  My expected output would be ShowName = v, Year = 2009, Season = 01, Episode = 13.  Same thing goes for space 1999 (1975).  ShowName = Space 1999, year = 1975

Comment: OK, that clarifies one thing, but `space 1999 (1975) v.2009.S01E13.the.title.avi` is ONE item in your list. Is that supposed to be two separate items? That would make much more sense.

Comment: I have updated the list to make those filenames separate items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some modifications to your regex, and it seems to work, if I understood you correctly.

```
^(
  (?P<ShowNameA>.*[^ (_.]) # Show name
    [ (_.]+
    ( # Year with possible Season and Episode
      (?P<ShowYearA>\d{4})
      ([ (_.]+S(?P<SeasonA>\d{1,2})E(?P<EpisodeA>\d{1,2}))?
    | # Season and Episode only
      (?<!\d{4}[ (_.])
      S(?P<SeasonB>\d{1,2})E(?P<EpisodeB>\d{1,2})
    | # Alternate format for episode
      (?P<EpisodeC>\d{3})
    )
|
  # Show name with no other information
  (?P<ShowNameB>.+)
)
```

See demo on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/mR6oD4/1)

**EDIT:** I've updated the regex to handle those last 3 situations you mentioned in comments.

One main problem was that you had no parens around the main alternation, so it included the whole regex. I also had to add an alternation to allow for none of the year/episode formats following the name.

Because you have so many different possible layouts that possibly conflict with each other, the regex ended up being lots of alternation of different scenarios. For example, to match a title that has no year or episode information at all, I had to add an alternation around the whole regex that if it can't find any known pattern, just match the whole thing.

Note: now that you seem to have expanded show years to match any four digits, there's no need for the lookahead. In other words, `(?=\d{4,4})(?P<ShowYear>\d{4})` is the same as `(?P<ShowYear>\d{4})`. This also means that your alternate format for episode must match 3 digits only, not 4. Otherwise, there's no way to distinguish a stand-alone 4-digit sequence as a year or episode.

General pattern:

```
[ (_.]+                   the delimiter used throughout
(?P<ShowNameA>.*[^ (_.])  the show name, greedy but not including a delimiter
(?P<ShowNameB>.+)         the show name when it's the whole line
```

Format A (Year with possible Season and Episode):

```
(?P<ShowYearA>\d{4})
([ (_.]+S(?P<SeasonA>\d{1,2})E(?P<EpisodeA>\d{1,2}))?
```

Format B (Season and Episode only):

```
(?<!\d{4}[ (_.])
S(?P<SeasonB>\d{1,2})E(?P<EpisodeB>\d{1,2})
```

Format C (Alternate format for episode):

```
(?P<EpisodeC>\d{3})
```

Comment: Thanks.  I took what you did and applied it to an updated expression.  It seems to work a lot better but is struggling with 3 file names still.  Can you check my updated section out in the original post?

Comment: @Talguy: I just updated my answer and it matches everything you need. That's my final answer; I need to move on. Hopefully it's ACCEPTable!

Comment: Thanks for all the help, this that does meet my needs.  This was my first adventure into regular expression.  It's confusing stuff, but thanks to your write up I see what you did and understand it.  Hopefully I can apply it to my next regex adventure.

Answer (score 0):

if i may, i adapted brian's regex to match something like

SHOW.NAME.201X.SXXEXX.XSUB.VOSTFR.720p.HDTV.x264-ADDiCTiON.mkv

here it is (PHP PCRE)

```
/^(
    (?P<ShowNameA>.*[^ (_.]) # Show name
        [ (_.]+
        ( # Year with possible Season and Episode
            (?P<ShowYearA>\d{4})
            ([ (_.]+S(?P<SeasonA>\d{1,2})E(?P<EpisodeA>\d{1,2}))?
        | # Season and Episode only
            (?<!\d{4}[ (_.])
            S(?P<SeasonB>\d{1,2})E(?P<EpisodeB>\d{1,2})
        )
|
        # Show name with no other information
        (?P<ShowNameB>.+)
)/mx
```

Comment: Sorry missed this suggestion.  It kind of works but not fully.  I ended up taking what Brian created and added flags to detect 720p and 480p keywords to avoid detecting them as the EpisodeC name group.  the below regex works with my test set and the test string you provided above.

^( (?P<ShowNameA>.*[^ (_.])
    [ (_.]+
    ( 
      (?P<ShowYearA>\d{4})
      ([ (_.]+S(?P<SeasonA>\d{1,2})E(?P<EpisodeA>\d{1,2}))?
    | 
      (?<!\d{4}[ (_.])
      S(?P<SeasonB>\d{1,2})E(?P<EpisodeB>\d{1,2})
    | (?P<EpisodeC>\d{3}[^720p|480p])
    )
|
    (?P<ShowNameB>.+)
)