# Regex - Stop at first reached match

Tags: regex, match, television

I was trying to match tv show names by regex. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807795/matching-tv-and-movie-file-names-with-regex) that provided me a good base for matching.
But that wasn't enough. I needed also to match something like

```
foo - 1x01
```

I managed to solve it adding "-" as escape character and new controls for the new format:

```
^(
  (?P<ShowNameA>.*[^ (_.-]) # Show name
    [ (_.-]+
    ( # Year with possible Season and Episode
      (?P<ShowYearA>\d{4})
      ([ (_.]+S(?P<SeasonA>\d{1,2})E(?P<EpisodeA>\d{1,2}))?
    | # Season and Episode only
      (?<!\d{4}[ (_.])
      S(?P<SeasonB>\d{1,2})E(?P<EpisodeB>\d{1,2})
    | # Year with possible Season and Episode f2
      (?P<ShowYearB>\d{4})
      ([ (_.]+(?P<SeasonC>\d{1,2})x(?P<EpisodeC>\d{1,2}))?
    | # Season and Episode only f2
      (?<!\d{4}[ (_.])
      (?P<SeasonD>\d{1,2})x(?P<EpisodeD>\d{1,2})
    | # Alternate format for episode
      (?P<EpisodeE>\d{3})
    )
|
  # Show name with no other information
  (?P<ShowNameB>.+)
)
```

But I noticed a bigger problem. If I test it with something like

```
foo - 1x01 - 720p
foo - 1x01 - 1080p
```

It will recognise 720 as episodeD and 1080p as YearA even if there's a match before. How can I change the regex to stop at first match?
Here's my edited regex
https://regex101.com/r/mR6oD4/16

Comment: Please add your regex to this question rather than relying on external links. People are less likely to click elsewhere and when that link goes down this question is useless for future readers.

Comment: And do you expect to get the `720` and `1080` values into group `EpisodeE`? Have a [look](https://regex101.com/r/kP7iS3/1).

Comment: @alex I added the regex immediately after posting.the link is just a plus

Comment: @user1143745 no that's the problem and what I want to avoid. I want it to get episodeD 01 seasonD 1